# Serve from Apache instead of IIS

Tags: windows, apache-2.4, iis-7, intranet

I am running Windows Small Business Server 2011 and I want to serve an Apache/PHP website from that machine, i.e. if I visit http://mylocalserver/ from within the network.

I understand that I cannot switch IIS off. I also understand that I can run PHP from IIS but I need Apache for .htaccess at the moment.

How do I get the server to serve from Apache instead of IIS?

Comment: Helicon Ape offers that functionality. http://www.helicontech.com/ape/

Answer (score 0):

Disable the ISS Service (World Wide Web Publishing Service), this will un-bind the service from the HTTP(S) ports.

Comment: Will that disable Remote Web Access?

Comment: As in traffic destined to this machine on www-80? Yes until you serve it with Apache, of which is what your plan is?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sue if IIS can be configured to bind exclusively to a nominated IP address but you can certainly run the Apache instance on a different port.

Comment: I am running Apache on a different port, which works locally, i.e. requesting `http://localhost:2016/` on the server itself, but not remotely. `http://mylocalserver:2016` from another machine just times out.

Comment: Then change your firewall.